# How to copy-paste a shape in PowerPoint in multiple slides?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have the following simple code that should copy a text-box from one array of slides and paste it in every other slide in a different array of slides:

```
aSlides[0].Shapes[2].Copy();

for (int p = 1; p <= all_lines_count; p++)
{
    sld_animation_steps[p - 1].Shapes.Paste();
}
```

However, the operation 'paste' is done multiple times on every slide, so for example, on slide five, I'll get five copies of the text-box overlapped, like if I have called Paste() five times, which I haven't. How do I fix this? I would appreciate any help.